# Which method to use for granting sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

What is the difference between adding a user to `/etc/sudoers` and `usermod -a -G sudo`?
Which method should be used for granting sudo?

Comment: For Ubuntu you should very strongly avoid editing the `/etc/sudoers` under any conditions.  Instead add config fragments into the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory.  Using the fragments folder makes upgrading easier since you modified a conffile.

Comment: @Zoredache - excellent point. Do you care if I add that to my answer? I don't want to take credit for it, but this tip should live in an answer somewhere in case the comment gods nuke this for some reason.

Comment: @EEAA, I grant you permission to use the above, and anyother comments I post to merge into actual answers.  I add comments because I am too lazy/busy to add a full answer, but I don't mind at if people take my comments and integrate them into a complete good answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you can avoid it, never grant sudo privileges to individual users. Always grant privilegs to a **group** and then add users to that group.

For ubuntu-based servers, instead of adding lines to `/etc/sudoers`, add config file fragments into `/etc/sudoers.d`. This is more flexible, easier to understand, more resilient in the face of upgrades, and works better with systems managed by configuration management systems.

NOTE: never edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. Instead, use `visudo`, which will perform syntax checking on your edits, preventing you from breaking your sudo config with invalid syntax.

Comment: why not add the group to `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno - right, that is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: ahhh... I thought you were referring to the `usermod -a -G sudo`

Comment: +1 for the warning about using visudo instead of direct edit

Comment: Good point about ``visudo``. Some people don't realize there's a reason that ``/etc/sudoers`` is marked as read-only.

Answer (score 9):

I just found this little tidbit out there... seems you need to be particularly careful with using the `-G` option in Ubuntu, in particular in combination `-g` option.  So:

1. Use **`usermod -aG`** to add the user(s) to a group.
2. Then ***as @EEAA suggested***, add the group to the /etc/sudoers file using the `$ sudo`**`visudo`** command (automatically invokes a privileged editor with syntax checking).

**Here's the info about the `-aG` option on Ubuntu, taken from here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240477:**

> 'I'm reading the **Wiley "Linux Command Line and Scripting Bible"** - and they said that usermod -G "appends" a group to whatever user account you are modifying. I found this to be false in Ubuntu, don't know if it's just different in other distro's, or a typo in the book. It removes you from EVERY other group you belong to, except your default user group (modified by the -g option). I managed to remove myself from the admin group and could no longer sudo anything. Thank goodness for recovery mode...'
>
> The correct option is *usermod -aG*. Lesson learned...

Comment: can the downvoter have the courtesy to provide some constructive criticism here.  tia.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your 'answer', doesn't really answer the question asked.  This is a pretty strict Q&A site, we generally expect answers to directly address the question asked.  BTW, yes I know you somewhat address the question a bit, but your 'answer' seems most saying do what EEAA said, but be warned about this weird quirk.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks for taking the time.  Doesn't step 1 & 2 clearly give instructions for "a preferred method for granting sudo"? Which is what the OP asked?

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us how big your environment is, but if it's more than one machine you may also want to consider [configuring `sudo` using LDAP](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.ldap.man.html) s an alternative to editing sudoers locally (either through `visudo` or using the `/etc/sudoers.d` fragments method).

LDAP configuration is a well-tested way of making sure that multiple machines have the same `sudo` configuration, and presents a nice unified environment (with central management of an important authorization mechanism).  As a bonus if you already use LDAP (or AD) for authentication/authorization in your environment you can take advantage of the existing infrastructure (and if you don't you should seriously consider it - centralization has many benefits).

Everything folks have already said in the other answers about creating authorized groups still stands - it's easier as you scale up to grant privileges to a group and manage group membership than it is to deal with managing rights for individual users.